# Divergence theorem & Kinetic model of plasmas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, differential-geometry, integration, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

In one section in my plasma physics notes (see below) on the Vlasov equation, 6D phase space & the kinetic model for plasma, I can't quite understand how (via Gauss's divergence theorem) this integral vanishes. This integral appears in the derivation of the conservation of energy for particles in a plasma, using the Vlasov equation.

In particular, I don't understand why we need to consider the modulus of the velocity going to infinity (which results in the distribution function going to zero) and I would like some insight as to how this affects the (closed) surface integral – it's quite hard to visualise.

> $$
> \int_{V} \mathrm{~d}^{3} x \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \cdot\left(\mathbf{v} f_{\alpha}\right)=\int_{S} \mathbf{v} f \cdot \mathrm{d} \mathbf{S}=0
> $$
> and this integral is zero because $f$ rapidly tends to zero when $|\mathbf{v}| \rightarrow \infty$.

**EDIT**: There is likely a typo in the quotation above; $|\mathbf{v}| \rightarrow \infty$ probably should be $|\mathbf{x}| \rightarrow \infty$.

**EDIT 2**: In addition, it says $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{v}} \cdot\left(\mathrm{v}^{2}\mathbf{a} f_{\alpha}\right) = 0$ "from Gauss theorem" (i.e. divergence theorem) later on in the notes too.

Comment: Surely they mean $|{\bf x}|\to \infty$?  The distribution $f$ can be taken to be zero at large distance  if the sytem is finite. If it is not finite then energy can can escape  from any fnite region  and so the  conservation law won't hold.

Comment: @mikestone Thanks, I think you're right, probably a typo in the notes. In this case, if $|\mathbf{x}| \rightarrow \infty$, then how does this relate to the divergence theorem here? I'm struggling to grasp how I can relate this to the dot product between $\mathbf{v}f$ and the vector surface element...

Comment: Isn't it just Stoke's theorem?  I assume that the $\partial/\partial {\bf x}\cdot (f{\bf v})$ means $\nabla\cdot (f{\bf v})= \partial_\mu (fv^\mu)$?

Comment: @mikestone Stokes' theorem is related to the curl, not the divergence, so Gauss's divergence theorem should be used. Yes, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \cdot$ represents divergence in $\mathbf{x}$-space. I'm probably missing something obvious here, but I still can't see how the integral vanishes in this case...

Comment: @mikestone In addition, it says $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{v}} \cdot\left(\mathrm{v}^{2}\mathbf{a} f_{\alpha}\right) = 0$ "from Gauss theorem" too.

Comment: True!  I'm careless with names because     there's really only on integration theorem: "Stokes' theorem" and "Gauss' theorem" are both examples of $ \int_{\partial \Omega} \omega= \int_{\Omega}d\omega$ which is usually called Stokes Theorem today. :)

Comment: Also the integral of $\nabla_{\bf v}|v|^2 {\bf a}f$ being zero really is because $f\to 0$ at large $|{\bf v}|$. That's probably the origin of the typo: --- cut and paste

Comment: @mikestone Thanks. The only bit that's bothering me now in the notes is a bit that states: "we can write:
$$
\int \mathrm{d}^{3} x[\mathbf{E} \cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{B})-\mathbf{B} \cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{E})]=-\int \mathrm{d}^{3} x \nabla \cdot(\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B})=\int_{S}(\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B}) \cdot \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{\sigma}=0
$$
as for $\mathbf{x} \rightarrow \infty$ the fields must go to zero, to keep energy finite." ...

Comment: @mikestone ... Again, this uses Gauss' divergence theorem. I do not get at all how the surface integral of this Poynting vector should be zero and so I have created another question for this... https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/602435/conservation-of-energy-poynting-vector/602440?noredirect=1#comment1355342_602440