# Conservation of Energy / Poynting vector

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, gauss-law, integration, poynting-vector

On [this](https://arxiv.org/html/physics/9908048v1/section6.htm) page, it states:

> "The only fields' couples (a,b) for which we can get a non-zero value
> of the Poynting vector for a large distance r₀ over the sphere are (R,
> R); (radiation, radiation) and (2, R); (relativistic, radiation). The
> reason is this. Spherical surface increases as r₀² and each field in
> these couples, onto this surface, decreases as 1/r₀ so, their product
> decreases as (1/r₀)². Consequently, even if r₀ goes to infinity,
> surface integral (eq.(33)) of the Poynting vector remains unchanged.
> In that case a well definite quantity of power goes out the sphere no
> matter the value of r₀ is. So, this energy is lost for ever."

Is there an error here, as surely each field decreases as $\frac{1}{r_{0}^{2}}$, meaning their product decreases as $\frac{1}{r_{0}^{4}}$?

For example, in my plasma physics notes, in the middle of a derivation of the conservation of energy (where $E^{f}$ is the energy of the EM fields) it states:

> $$ \begin{aligned} \frac{\mathrm{d} E^{f}}{\mathrm{~d} t}=& \varepsilon_{0} \int \mathrm{d}^{3} x \mathbf{E} \cdot\left[\frac{1}{\varepsilon_{0} \mu_{0}} \nabla \times \mathbf{B}-\frac{1}{\varepsilon_{0}} \mathrm{j}\right]+\frac{1}{\mu_{0}} \int \mathrm{d}^{3} x \mathbf{B} \cdot(-\nabla \times \mathbf{E})=\\ &-\int \mathrm{d}^{3} x \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{E}+\frac{1}{\mu_{0}} \int \mathrm{d}^{3} x \mathbf{E} \cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{B})-\frac{1}{\mu_{0}} \int \mathrm{d}^{3} x \mathbf{B} \cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{E}) \end{aligned} $$ Using the vector identity $$ \nabla \cdot(\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B})=\mathbf{B} \cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{E})-\mathbb{E} \cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{B}) $$ we can write: $$ \int \mathrm{d}^{3} x[\mathbf{E} \cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{B})-\mathbf{B} \cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{E})]=-\int \mathrm{d}^{3} x \nabla \cdot(\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B})=\int_{S}(\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B}) \cdot \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{\sigma}=0 $$ as for $\mathbf{x} \rightarrow \infty$ the fields must go to zero, to keep energy finite.

This suggests that the fields decrease much faster than the surface enclosing them increases, meaning no flux traverses the surface at infinity, which contradicts the webpage quoted at the top of this question. I am quite confused by both of these explanations and would like to know the conditions/cases in which the surface integral of the Poynting vector does indeed vanish.

**EDIT**: *Note, for energy conservation in this case,*
$\frac{\mathrm{d} E^{f}}{\mathrm{~d} t}= -\int \mathrm{d}^{3} x\ \mathbf{j} \cdot\mathbf{E}$ $ $
*must be satisfied.*

Answer (score 1):

> Surely each field decreases as $1/r_0^2$

No. The inverse-square dependence of Coulomb’s Law doesn’t apply to accelerating charges. Look at the dependence on distance of the [Liénard-Wiechert fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#Field_computation) of a point charge in arbitrary motion. The term proportional to the acceleration decreases as $1/r_0$, not $1/r_0^2$, and causes the Poynting flux to be nonzero at infinity.

Comment: Oh ok, I see... So, in a non-relativistic limit, the fields decrease as ~ $\frac{1}{\mathrm{r_{0}}}$ for accelerating charges?

Comment: Not just in the non-relativistic limit. The LW fields are valid for any velocity.

Comment: BTW, I looked only briefly at that paper you’re reading, but it seemed like it might be non-mainstream. I recommend treating it with skepticism.

Comment: The Wikipedia link in your answer has a $\frac{1}{\mathrm{r}}$ and a $\frac{1}{\mathrm{r^{2}}}$ dependence but the $\frac{1}{\mathrm{r^{2}}}$ term is multiplied by the Lorentz factor...

Comment: Yes... I just found that webpage while trying to figure out the reasoning in my plasma notes (quoted near the end of my question). I still can't work out why the integral vanishes here...

Comment: *I still can't work out why the integral vanishes here* I don’t think it does, but I might be missing something.

Comment: The integral has to vanish, otherwise the magnitude of $\frac{\mathrm{d} E^{f}}{\mathrm{~d} t}$ for the fields would not be equal to that of the particles in the plasma, $\frac{\mathrm{d} E^{p}}{\mathrm{~d} t}$, which is necessary for energy to be conserved.

Comment: As an example, if we used the reasoning that the fields go to zero at infinite distance "to keep energy finite", then we could erroneously conclude for Gauss's Law that the closed surface integral for enclosed charges is zero (instead of $\frac{\mathrm{Q}}{\epsilon_{0}}$), since the electric field would go to zero if we took the limit of an infinite radius!?

Comment: I guess that they are ignoring radiation.

Comment: Anything in gen-ph on the Arxiv is probably cranky, and this paper seems to be violating any number of the theorems..

Comment: I don’t see how the reasoning in your notes makes sense, as your comment indicates. The fields can go to zero as $1/r$ and the surface integral over an infinitely large sphere at infinity (for either the flux of the electric field or the flux of the Poynting vector) can still be nonzero. The final integral is zero only if there is no $1/r$ radiative field. I don’t know plasma physics, but it seems likely that the radiative field falls off faster than $1/r$ when there are many charges accelerating in random directions.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, I now reckon it's to do with Debye screening and the concept of quasi-neutrality: once you view the plasma on length scales larger than the Debye length, the plasma is effectively neutral and thus you can probably just say that the fields have 'vanished'.